pubsub pull subscription in GKE cluster with multiple pods
I have a pubsub subscriber which checks for new file in gs bucket. Once the file arrives in gs bucket, I need to parse it and send to specific bigquery table based on id in the bucket path.
For that, I have python code which uses pubsub subscriber to check new file in gs bucket. Once file arrives, it will check for the id in bucket path such as gs://bucket/...//file1.txt. There could be 6 ids folders in which files will arrive. Based on if else condition of id number, the bigquery will perform load_table_from_uri() to send it to different table and ack() or nack() the message. The frequency of file availability is not consistent, i.e. there could be 10 files of GB in size in 1 minute, or 1 file per 5 minutes. I see that pubsub has provided the yml for k8 along with HPA.
So, my question is, if I use GKE k8s cluster with 3-5 replica of pods, could all pods get same gs file path via pubsub and process them at same time resulting duplicate records in bigquery table? or how does it work?
Also, should I use filtered subscription with per app in k8s cluster per id, or current setup with if else condition would be fine based on cost and efficiency?

If all of your replicas use the same subscription, then messages will be load balanced across them. Typically, a message will only be received by one of them. However, Pub/Sub has at-least-once delivery guarantees, which means that a duplicate message could be delivered (including a message for which you called ack()). In such cases, there is no guarantee which replica will receive the duplicate; it could be the one that received the original delivery, it could be a different one. In general, your subscriber needs to be resilient to duplicate delivery.
Filters are useful if you want each app to receive a specific subset of messages that you can determine via the attributes at subscription creation time. The use of filters won't help with the duplicate delivery issue other than limiting duplicates to the same app instance. Keep in mind that such duplicates could happen after a restart of a node, though, so you wouldn't be able to rely on in-memory state to catch such dupes.
